# csv data to html table

Tags: php, html, csv

I need to get data from an `CSV` file to an HTML table with php. I've did it with filtering and that works like a charm. Now i tried adding it if `$filter` isn't there but for some reason it puts it outside the table.

my code for getting `$filter`:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $filter = $_POST["search"];
}
```

so there wont be any variable with the name $filter if there is no `POST` request.

here is my code for getting the csv data to a HTML table:

```
if (($HandleAnalog = fopen("csv/Analog/ADC_DAC.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

echo "<table id='ADC_DAC' style='width:100%; border: 1px solid black;'>";
while (($data = fgetcsv($HandleAnalog, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {

    $num = count($data);
    $row++;

    if(strpos($data[4],$filter) !== false || strpos($data[2],$filter) !== false ||strpos($data[5],$filter) !== false){
        echo "<tr style='border: 1px solid black;'>";
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            if ($row == 0) {
                echo "<th style='border: 1px solid black;'>";
                $dat = str_replace(',', '.', $data[$c]);
                echo $dat;
                echo "</th>";
                $row++;
            }
            echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>";
            $dat = str_replace(',', '.', $data[$c]);
            echo $dat;
            echo "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }else if ($filter == null) {
        echo "<tr style='border: 1px solid black;'>";
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            if ($row == 0) {
                echo "<th style='border: 1px solid black;'>";
                $dat = str_replace(',', '.', $data[$c]);
                echo $dat;
                echo "</th>";
                $row++;
            }
            echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>";
            $dat = str_replace(',', '.', $data[$c]);
            echo $dat;
            echo "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo "</table>";
}

    fclose($HandleAnalog);
```

But for some reason it doesn't show the data when I don't filter it, while I did exactly the same.

How it looks when i Filter:

[image: While Filtering]

How it looks when I don't filter:

[image: While not filtering]

And if I look at the elements in my browser I see that it closes the table before the non-filtered values are.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I can't find the problem in your code. Are you sure that when you're filtering $filter is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please initialize $filter, because you are testing for an unset variable (several warnings or notices can impact PHP performance, even if error reporting is disabled)
2. Initialize $filter to null
3. First evaluate for the absence of $filter (Just my suggestion, not a rule, but would be faster to ommit calling functions when there is nothing to search...)

So:

```
$filter = null;
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $filter = $_POST["search"];
}

echo "<table id='ADC_DAC' style='width:100%; border: 1px solid black;'>";
while (($data = fgetcsv($HandleAnalog, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {

  $num = count($data);
  $row++;

  if ($filter == null) {
      echo "<tr style='border: 1px solid black;'>";
      for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
          if ($row == 0) {
              echo "<th style='border: 1px solid black;'>";
              $dat = str_replace(',', '.', $data[$c]);
              echo $dat;
              echo "</th>";
              $row++;
          }
          echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>";
          $dat = str_replace(',', '.', $data[$c]);
          echo $dat;
          echo "</td>";
      }
      echo "</tr>";
  }else if(strpos($data[4],$filter) !== false || strpos($data[2],$filter) !== false ||strpos($data[5],$filter) !== false){
      echo "<tr style='border: 1px solid black;'>";
      for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
          if ($row == 0) {
              echo "<th style='border: 1px solid black;'>";
              $dat = str_replace(',', '.', $data[$c]);
              echo $dat;
              echo "</th>";
              $row++;
          }
          echo "<td style='border: 1px solid black;'>";
          $dat = str_replace(',', '.', $data[$c]);
          echo $dat;
          echo "</td>";
      }
      echo "</tr>";
  }
}
echo "</table>";
}

fclose($HandleAnalog);
```

Comment: Hi, just got home from work so i cant test it now. I tought it wouldnt make a difference if i'd say $filter == 0 or i'd just dont make a variable $filter at all. But thanks for the answer and you'll hear more of me tomorrow :)